# Load Excel on a sharepoint folder to SQL Server using SSIS without saving a local copy

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, ssis

I have created a simple SSIS task to load data from excel file on a sharepoint folder to a sql server.

I have another code that replaces the file on the sharepoint folder with an updated that has same template and filename.
This data load from excel to sql works for the first time however fails when I try to run it even locally and works only after I edit the connect details again by selecting the same file using explorer.

Can you please advise if there is a better way of automating the data load (May be a script task but without having to save a copy locally). Please advise.